# Can you use the split function in different orders?

Tags: python, split

I recently watched a video about the split function. They introduced `maxsplit` which can split strings after encountering the specified element after a certain number of times.

Here is an example:

```py
'01104,USA,NYC,August,2020'.split(',' ,maxsplit=1)
```

Which produces:

```
['01104', 'USA,NYC,August,2020']
```

What if the first and third commas separated so it would be like
`'01104' , 'USA,NYC' , 'August,2020'`

How should I code it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the split function let you do this, but you can always split your string to every comma and recombine certains parts later like this:

```
s = '01104,USA,NYC,August,2020'.split(',')
s = [s[0],
     s[1]+","+s[2],
     s[3]+","+s[4]]
```

So s would be equal to `['01104' , 'USA,NYC' , 'August,2020']`